# knockoutjs template displays before viewModel loads/binds

Tags: knockout.js

I am using Knockoutjs templates. The page is loaded with the template html showing for a brief second and then after the viewModel is loaded and binded, it displays correctly. What is the best way to deal with this? Currently I am wrapping the template in a div that is set to display: none and then removing this after the bindings have been applied.

Comment: Templates have a specific meaning with knockout, it sounds like you mean the base html of the page, correct?

Comment: No I mean my page starts off as <div data-bind="foreach: Blah">something</div> and it shows "something" before knockoutjs interprets all of the data-bind attributes and figures out how to display the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping your markup in a script tag:

```
<script type="text/html" id="viewModelTemplate">
... your markup ...
</script>
```

and then having a single top level element of:

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'viewModelTemplate'}"/>
```

could help.

Answer (score 0):

When are you binding your view model?  Are you doing it from an AJAX request or an event?  If the data is there, a script tag at the bottom of your page should run and do the bindings before any HTML is displayed.  If you need the binding to run after the HTML is displayed, you need to use your method.  If you are using AJAX, I'd structure the view model such that you bind to your empty view model and have a property like `isLoaded` that you set when the loading is complete, then you can bind to it:

```
<div data-bind="visible: isLoaded">...</div>
```

Comment: If the script tag is at the bottom of the page, the page will have been rendered before the javascript loads. It might seem like it hasn't if you have a very small number of scripts to load.